# How do I curl multiple resources in one command?

Tags: bash, curl

Say I am trying to download a set of 50 lecture notes efficiently. These notes are inside the `prof` subdirectory of a university website. The 45th lecture note is inside the `lect45` subdirectory as a pdf entitled `lect45.pdf`. I get my first pdf as follows:

```
curl -O http://www.university.edu/~prof/lect1/lect1.pdf
```

How do I get all my 50 notes efficiently using cURL and bash? I'm trying to do this from the command line, not through a Python / Ruby / Perl script. I know something like the below will generate a lot of 404s:

```
curl -O http://www.university.edu/~prof/lect{1..50}/lect{1..50}.pdf
```

so what will work better? I would prefer an elegant one-liner over a loop.

Comment: `I know something like the below won't work` Why? It will

Comment: @hek2mgl won't really work: the numbers won't really be sync'ed.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Understand. But thats a bash problem, not a curl problem

Comment: @hek2mgl because I've tried it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do it in several processes:

```
for i in {1..50}
do
    curl -O http://www.university.edu/~prof/lect$i/lect$i.pdf &
done
```

or as a one-liner (just a different formatting):

```
for i in {1..50}; do curl -O http://www.university.edu/~prof/lect$i/lect$i.pdf & done
```

The `&` makes all processes run in parallel.

Don't be scared by the output; the shell tells you that 50 processes have been started, that's a lot of spam.  Later it will tell you for each of these that they terminated.  A lot of output again.

You probably don't want to run all 50 in parallel ;-)

EDIT:

Your example using `{1..50}` twice makes a matrix of the numbers.  See for example `echo {1..3}/{1..3}` to see what I mean.  And I guess that this way you create a lot of 404s.

Comment: I expect curl having it's own, *better* paralelism.

Comment: You do?  "Do one thing well" – the Unix philosophy.  Use the OS for the concurrency.  You might be right nevertheless, but I found none.

Comment: That does not apply here. It is important that the documents will be outputted one after another, in the order you passed them via command line. (like cat, that's why the name cat-url, curl). OS will not guarantee this.. Your answer is simply wrong

Comment: Why do you think that the order is important?

Comment: I see now what you mean, thanks for pointing that out.  But the option given here (`-O`) makes the output being written to a local file of a proper name.  So it does not work like `cat`.  Hence my answer should be right.

Comment: ;) don't worry about the down-vote. I don't like this too much as well, but the asnwers were just wrong

Comment: You probably didn't see the last edit of my last comment here about the used option `-O`.

Comment: Ok, with the `-O` option it makes sense +1

Comment: `&` makes the command be run in a background process, so the loop continues at once.  Without the `&` the command gets run in a foreground process, the shell waits for its execution termination and only then continues with the loop.  So then all get downloaded sequentially.

Comment: You can, of course, write my solution in one line.  You cannot, however, get rid of a loop in case you want to do several things (download 50 lectures).  You can at most hide the loop by using a tool which does the loop for you, for instance as given in the `parallel` answer.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [`parallel`](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#example__download_10_images_for_each_of_the_past_30_days) shell tool.

So, for this particular case it will look like

```
seq 50 | parallel curl -O http://www.university.edu/~prof/lect{}/lect{}.pdf
```

As for `curl` - it doesn't have its own parallel mechanism, and what for it actually should? And your example with shell expansions `{1..50}` seems valid for me.

Comment: It is important that the documents will be outputted one after another, in the order you passed them via command line. (like cat, that's why the name cat-url, curl). `parallel` will not guarantee this.. Your answer is simply wrong

Comment: hek2mgl, here also the option `-O` applies (as it already comes from the original question), so your comment is as wrong as it was on my answer.

Comment: Btw, I like `parallel`, so I can upvote this answer as well ;-)

Comment: @Alfe Yes, I've seen this and I'm sorry. I didn't took this into account unless you pointed me towards this in your comment. But SO doesn't allow to remove that dwon-vote unless the answer will be edited again. (yours was edited) ...

Comment: Can you remove your comment?  Would that count as an edit?  I can remove my downvotes, might be a privilege thing based on reputation.  But then again, you've got more than me …

Comment: @hek2mgl "curl" is not short for "cat-url": http://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#What_is_cURL

Comment: @Alfe You can remove a down-vote 5 minutes after you've down-voted. After this time the post must be edited before you can remove your vote. Sometimes this is a little bit annoying like in this case: You showed me that I'm wrong but the down-vote was already older than 5 minutes. However, now it was edited and I turned my down-vote in to an up-vote..

Comment: Wasn't aware of that 5-minute limit.